# Consume OData on Android

Tags: java, android, odata, odata4j

I'm trying to consume an OData API using the odata4j library for Android but keep getting an error. The example I'm using is in their page: http://odata4j.org/

I installed the odata4j library (odata4j-dist-0.7.0-clientbundle) on my Android project and ran:

```
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumer;
import org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers;
import org.odata4j.core.OEntity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String serviceUrl = "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/";
        ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumers.create(serviceUrl);

        for (OEntity category : consumer.getEntities("Categories").execute()) {
            String categoryName = category.getProperty("Name", String.class).getValue();
            System.out.println("Category name: " + categoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my log (since the body is limited to 30000 characters, I can't had the all log) :

> Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB 06-07 08:01:02.119 19535-
>   19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels E/ProviderFactory: The
>   provider class, class
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App,
>   could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will
>   not be utilized
>       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.Types.getTypeArray(Types.java:50)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:265)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:158)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:187)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:151)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:141)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:163)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:134)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:232)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:149)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:153)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:145)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:275)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:150)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:476)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.DefaultJerseyClientFactory.createClient(DefaultJerseyClientFactory.java:22)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.JerseyClientUtil.newClient(JerseyClientUtil.java:53)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.(ODataJerseyClient.java:59)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:25)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:36)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.build(ODataConsumers.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(ODataConsumers.java:115)
>           at com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>         at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(Paramet 06-07 08:01:02.127 19535-19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels
>   E/ProviderFactory: The provider class, class
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text,
>   could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will
>   not be utilized
>       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.Types.getTypeArray(Types.java:50)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:265)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:158)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:187)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:151)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:141)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:163)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:134)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:232)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:149)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:153)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:145)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:275)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:150)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:476)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.DefaultJerseyClientFactory.createClient(DefaultJerseyClientFactory.java:22)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.JerseyClientUtil.newClient(JerseyClientUtil.java:53)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.(ODataJerseyClient.java:59)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:25)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:36)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.build(ODataConsumers.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(ODataConsumers.java:115)
>           at com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>         at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(Parame 06-07 08:01:02.130 19535-19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels
>   E/ProviderFactory: The provider class, class
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General,
>   could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will
>   not be utilized
>       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.Types.getTypeArray(Types.java:50)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:265)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:158)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:187)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:151)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:141)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:163)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:134)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:232)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:149)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:153)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:145)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:275)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:150)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:476)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.DefaultJerseyClientFactory.createClient(DefaultJerseyClientFactory.java:22)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.JerseyClientUtil.newClient(JerseyClientUtil.java:53)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.(ODataJerseyClient.java:59)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:25)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:36)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.build(ODataConsumers.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(ODataConsumers.java:115)
>           at com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>         at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(Par 06-07 08:01:02.271 19535-19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels
>   E/ProviderFactory: The provider class, class
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App,
>   could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will
>   not be utilized
>       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.Types.getTypeArray(Types.java:50)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:265)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:158)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:187)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:151)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:141)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:163)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:134)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:232)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:149)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:171)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:146)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:275)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:150)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:476)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.DefaultJerseyClientFactory.createClient(DefaultJerseyClientFactory.java:22)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.JerseyClientUtil.newClient(JerseyClientUtil.java:53)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.(ODataJerseyClient.java:59)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:25)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:36)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.build(ODataConsumers.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(ODataConsumers.java:115)
>           at com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>         at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(Paramet 06-07 08:01:02.287 19535-19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels
>   E/ProviderFactory: The provider class, class
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text,
>   could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will
>   not be utilized
>       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.Types.getTypeArray(Types.java:50)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:265)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:158)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:187)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:151)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:141)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:163)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:134)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:232)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:149)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:171)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:146)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:275)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:150)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:476)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.DefaultJerseyClientFactory.createClient(DefaultJerseyClientFactory.java:22)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.JerseyClientUtil.newClient(JerseyClientUtil.java:53)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.(ODataJerseyClient.java:59)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:25)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:36)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.build(ODataConsumers.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(ODataConsumers.java:115)
>           at com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>         at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(Parame 06-07 08:01:02.300 19535-19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels
>   E/ProviderFactory: The provider class, class
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General,
>   could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will
>   not be utilized
>       java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:67)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:76)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getResolvedType(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:75)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.resolveTypes(ListOfTypes.java:70)
>           at libcore.reflect.ListOfTypes.getResolvedTypes(ListOfTypes.java:55)
>           at libcore.reflect.Types.getTypeArray(Types.java:50)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:265)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.getGenericParameterTypes(Constructor.java:158)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getConstructor(ComponentConstructor.java:187)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor._getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:151)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:141)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:163)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:134)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:232)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:149)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:171)
>           at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:146)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:275)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.(Client.java:150)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:476)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.DefaultJerseyClientFactory.createClient(DefaultJerseyClientFactory.java:22)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.JerseyClientUtil.newClient(JerseyClientUtil.java:53)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyClient.(ODataJerseyClient.java:59)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:25)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer.(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:14)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.jersey.consumer.ODataJerseyConsumer$Builder.build(ODataJerseyConsumer.java:36)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.build(ODataConsumers.java:93)
>           at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.create(ODataConsumers.java:115)
>           at com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>         at libcore.reflect.ParameterizedTypeImpl.getRawType(Par 06-07
>
> ```
> --------- beginning of crash 06-07 08:01:02.478 19535-19535/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> ```
>
> EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.nelsu.meo_channels, PID: 19535
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nelsu.meo_channels/com.example.nelsu.meo_channels.MainActivity}:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)

Comment: I see `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` which means you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/295004 but with the small section of code and cut-off error message it could be something else.

Comment: @MorrisonChang that code is all I have since is the example. I can post all the log if you think it may help. I'll check that question anyway, thank you!

Comment: If you don't find it to be a Network On Main Thread problem, do expand your question to include how and where your are testing your code snippet and do post the full log. See: [Which is the correct symbol to format logcat error output?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269418/159081) and indent as needed.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I had some more code from my class but that is all I have, it's just a simple example to start up. About the log, I had all I could since there are limitations about the char number.

Comment: Back to the link I provided, put your code in at least a AsyncTask, I'm assuming that the `consumer.getEntities("Categories").execute()` call will attempt to do network activity which shouldn't be on UI thread. Your history shows some prior Android work so you should have encountered this before. The other issue may be that the library is 'old' and may not maintained. Found: https://code.google.com/archive/p/odata4j/source/android/source which may help or you may want to look at [Apache Olingo](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/download.html) which has a more recent release.